# Can an everywhere continuous real function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be strictly increasing at only one point?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

My definition of "strictly increasing at one point" is Did's definition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/364619). I'll type it out here anyway:

A function $f$ is increasing at $x$ if $f(t)\gt f(x)$ for every $t\gt x$ close enough to $x$ and $f(t)\lt f(x)$ for every $t\lt x$ close enough to $x$. More rigorously, one asks that there exists $\varepsilon\gt0$ such that, for every $(t,s)$ such that $x-\varepsilon\lt t\lt x\lt s\lt x+\varepsilon$, $f(t)\lt f(x)\lt f(s)$.

My question is:

> Can an everywhere continuous real function be strictly increasing at
> only one point?

I think this is harder to prove than first meets the eye: for example we cannot use [the fact that a monotone function has limits from the left and right at every point of it's domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044938/monotonic-function-limits-from-the-right-and-from-the-left), because to use it we would need to assume our function is monotone which I don't think is closely related to what we are trying to show. Also, trying to use this theorem on an interval of the domain (either including $0$ or excluding $0$) doesn't really help, as far as I can see.

My attempt, which I think is correct, but would like verification (of one step in particular):

Suppose without loss of generality that $f$ is strictly increasing at the point $x=0$ only. Then $f$ is decreasing everywhere else, that is, when $x\neq 0.$

$f$ is strictly increasing at $x=0,\ $ therefore $\exists \varepsilon>0\ $ such that for every $\ t,s\ $ such that $-\varepsilon<t<0<s<\varepsilon,\quad f(t)<f(0)<f(s).\quad $ Therefore $\frac{-\varepsilon}{2}<0\quad$ with $\ u = f(-\frac{\varepsilon}{2})<f(0).\quad$ But $f$ is decreasing for all $x< 0,\ $ so therefore $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x) \leq u <f(0)\ \ (*),\ $ contradicting the continuity at $x=0.$

Is $(*)$ obviously true? Is it good enough, or do I need to prove it with definitions? Or is this a matter of taste?

Edit: Clearly the above proof is faulty, as I found out in the comments. My statement at the beginning of the proof, "Then $f$ is decreasing everywhere else, that is, when $x\neq 0.$" is unjustified. It seems the problem remains open.

Comment: I think your argument is fine, but a little too complicated perhaps. By your definition, a function is strictly increasing at $x$ if it is strictly increasing in some open set $(x-\varepsilon, x+ \varepsilon) = U$. But now $f$ is strictly increasing at every point of $U$, not only at $x$.

Comment: @LurchiDerLurch that's not true. In Did's answer in the first link he gives a counterexample to your claim. "...Consider for example the function $f$ defined by $f(t)=2t$ for every rational $t$ and $f(t)=t$ for every irrational $t$. Then $f$ is increasing at $x=0$ and only at $x=0$".

Comment: But this is not a continuous function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Comment: Where do you get that not increasing = decreasing?

Comment: That's true, but your claim, that a function is strictly increasing at $x$ if it is strictly increasing in some open set $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)=U$ would need to be proven... I don't see how this claim is obvious.

Comment: It seems clear that this is not possible: in $\mathbb R$ any number has a consecutive so strict  increasing in a point $x$ must imply strict increasing in other $y$ in the neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: @MarkSaving wow, you're totally right. My sentence, "Then $f$ is decreasing everywhere else, that is, when $x\neq 0.$" is unjustified...

Comment: I am sorry, I just realized I misread your definition!

Comment: If you're trying to find a counterexample, it suffices to find a function $f : (-a, a) \to \mathbb{R}$ which is increasing only at 0. We can extend $f$ to the real line by making $g$ a decreasing linear function for $|x| \geq a/2$ but matching $g$ with $f$ when $|x| \leq a/2$.

Comment: Of some relevance is Paramanand Singh's answer to [Proof verification : $f$ is increasing at $x_0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2295819/13130) and my [16 May 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/9kU61P-TLOs/m/H7bsXeNAHrkJ).

Comment: Also, constructions like the Weierstrass function make it clear that even for continuous functions, strictly inc at a point does not imply strictly inc in some neighborhood of that point.

Comment: Also, see Brown/Darji/Larsen's [*Nowhere monotone functions and functions of nonmonotonic type*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1999-127-01/S0002-9939-99-04571-2/S0002-9939-99-04571-2.pdf), **Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society** 127 #1 (January 1999), 173-182 for one literature entry point to these notions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $W(x)$ be the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), which is continuous, but is nowhere strictly monotone. Wikipedia: "Rather between any two points no matter how close, the function will not be monotone."

Then I believe $f(x) = x|W(x)|$ is continuous (product of continuous functions is continuous), and strictly increasing only at $x=0$, although I don't know how to prove that this function is not strictly increasing at $x\neq 0,$ though if true, it is probably similar to proving that the Weierstrass function itself is nowhere strictly monotone.

I can see that the Weierstrass function is defined differently in wikipedia and wolframalpha. I think my answer will work either way.

Comment: *probably similar to proving* --- There's a huge difference, since there exist **everywhere (finitely) differentiable functions** (even a bounded derivative) that are nowhere monotone (i.e. not monotone in any interval). However, I think this will work because at each point at least one of the Dini derivates of the Weierstrass function is $+\infty$ and at least one of the Dini derivates of the Weierstrass function is $-\infty.$ For example, see GH from MO's answer to [Does the Weierstrass function have a point of increase?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/77200/15780). **(continued)**

Comment: Incidentally, not all nowhere differentiable continuous functions have this property -- the Takaga function, for example, has a two-sided derivative of $+\infty$ at a lot of points and a two-sided derivative of $-\infty$ at a lot of points. Here "a lot of points" is uncountably many in every interval. In fact, even more is true -- Hausdorff dimension $1$ (maximum possible for a subset of the reals) in every interval, this despite the fact that the set of such points has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: Yeah, I had an idea to do something like this. But the details are tricky and nasty, and it's not at all "obvious" that things work out.

Comment: Incidentally, and after this I really need to go (I wasn't planning on spending nearly an hour here!), the same result about infinite derivates holds for $xW(x)$ since (roughly speaking) the local growth rate of $f(x) = x$ is bounded at each point and thus is not sufficient to prevent the infinite derivate behavior.

Comment: I wonder if we could do something like this to the weierstrass function to make it increasing at 0? https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOaoI.png